How can nickel be used in lithium-ion batteries if the two metals cannot share an electrolyte?
The Wikipedia page on lithium-nickel batteries (among others) says that nickel and lithium cannot share an electrolyte in a battery, and that this problem is not easily overcome.....
There can be two, partially separated (by porous glass) electrolytes, but... is that what is done in modern lithium-ion batteries containing nickel?
Do you only need one electrolyte if only one metal of the two is contributing ions?
Somehow, I cannot find a simple answer....
